# Does anyone know how to add ActionListener to an array of buttons?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm creating a project and its similar to mancala. I add `ActionListener` to an array of buttons with a loop and call the separated handler. At first run I thought it was okay, GUI shows up but when I clicked buttons it was working but the CLI says a lot of errors. On the second running, same code the GUI doesn't show up anymore and CLI says:

```
Exception in main java lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:8
```

(And other stuff.)

Here's my code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
for( int i = 0; i<=8; i++ )
{btnPods[i].addActionListener( handler ); }
```

**Is this right?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since java 1.5 (read since long time ago) you can use for-each loop, this will save you from thinking about the array indices:

```
JButton [] btnPods = ...
Handler handler = new Handler();

for(JButton btnPod : btnPods) {
    btnPod.addActionListener(handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ooh.. I've found the problem. Its out of bounds because the condition is <= 8 it starts at 0 so it should be <= 7 or < 8. I changed it to i <= 7. But is there any other ways to `addActionlistener` to a button or what I did is fine?

I'm currently new here and I'm looking for lovely people to respond, I'm really searching for a lot of answers